# Warning: file_get_contents failed to open stream: Connection timed out in includes/simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Tags: php

All of a sudden my cronjob has stopped working properly where it grabs content through file_get_contents and started giving the following warning and fatal error. Does anyone know why it is doing this?:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://seriesgate.me/search/indv_episodes/The+Social+Network): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in includes/simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in includes/seriesgate.class.php on line 25
```

Comment: If http://seriesgate.me is your domain then check 75 number line of includes/simple_html_dom.php. On this line it is including or requiring some other file which may be not exists or the file permissions are not proper. Fatal error says that on line number 25 of includes/seriesgate.class.php you are going to use a function find() from an object. But, that is not an object. Try to solve out first one may be the second one dependent on that.

Comment: What changed at the time it stopped working?  Did your system have something changed?  An update?  Permission changes?

Comment: Nothing that I am aware of was changed, it stopped out of nowhere. My host claims nothing was changed to cause it.

Comment: Do you think maybe SeriesGate has banned my server's IP from connecting to their website which is causing the connection to time out?

Answer (score -1):

Its working.

```
echo file_get_contents("http://seriesgate.me/search/indv_episodes/The+Social+Network");
```

It may be execution problem.

Try this

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
echo file_get_contents("http://seriesgate.me/search/indv_episodes/The+Social+Network");
```

Comment: I wonder why my cronjob fails to run it successfully then? It used to work fine but recently began doing this.

Comment: It may a execution time problem. Kindly try the above code

Comment: Which file do I put that code in? seriesgate.class.php or simple_html_dom.php

Comment: Adding that did not fix it. Same warning and fatal error.

Answer (score -1):

The `Connection timed out` error is a network problem for sure.

First, that's maybe your network connection problem take too long to get response from server. Please check your local/server/hosting internet connection; domain name, IP, port,... typo.

Secondly, that's maybe destination problem. For example, [seriesgate.me is down for everyone, not only you](http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/seriesgate.me.html). I know this question is 3 years old and the site is down. But this is best practice that you should check your destination when it's say something like `Connection timed out`.