# file_get_content Error?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hosting, file-get-contents

Everything is working fine on localhost but first I host the website after up and downs and overcoming over I got stuck at this problem:

```
file_get_contents(http://....): failed to open stream: Connection timed out
```

I have not used `file_get_function` anywhere in my code but it is giving the error. Where is this coming from?

What does `Connection time out` mean? I checked on SOF but I get more and more confused. Any help will be appreciated!

Can anyone give a detailed explanation or link?

Comment: Your application is trying to connect to a server and gets a timeout error.?

Comment: how can i fix that....

Comment: already asked checked following

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189973/file-get-contents-connection-timed-out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545671/warning-file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-connection-timed-out-in-includ

Comment: i have not used this function anywhere in my code from where i am getting this error.....and where should i edit or look for error http://ershadow.5gbfree.com/koopanda/koopanda/ my link for website now i am getting another error

Comment: "where the hell this comes from" - the error message gives you a file name and a line number (File: /usr/share/php/footer.php, Line: 11) ...

Comment: no such directory exist

Comment: What does `$c = file_get_contents('/usr/share/php/footer.php'); echo '# ', $c[10], ' #';` print?

Comment: oops, I meant `file(''/usr/share/php/footer.php');` instead of `file_get_contents` - but anyway, the output shows that there _is_ such a file in that directory. Maybe you do not have control over this part of the webpage (and the file system),

Comment: $content = file_get_contents($url) this is now the output still i am struggling with problem

Comment: You could revert to file_get_contents() and `echo '<pre>', htmlentities($c), '</pre>';` to inspect the complete file. If you're sure it's not yours ask the webhost. Maybe (just wild guessing) it's part of your free hosting agreement?

Answer (score 0):

There could be two main reasons for this:

- Your server cannot resolve the domain name (try `nslookup` from shell) - if this is the problem, you can try to set Google nameservers (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4)
- There are firewall restrictions, which do not allowed to make inbound/outbound connection from your server

> You can try out a cURL connection instead, maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents() does not deal with slow network connections or redirects for getting remote files. You can use fsockopen() which allow a custom connection timeout value
try to use cURL

Comment: redirects - the http wrapper used for file_get_contents(http:....) by default does follow redirects, see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.follow-location

Answer (score 0):

See this TIP in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the [fopen
>   wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to
>   specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for
>   links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have,
>   notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they
>   may provide.

If your live site does not have `allow_url_fopen = On` then this function will not allow you to use url's